The system shortcuts like "Computer Management" keep resetting their position on Windows 10 desktop
When I create a shortcut for any MMC service (e.g. "Computer Management") on my desktop, it keeps resetting its position on reboot.

I've solved this issue by removing the [LocalizedFileNames] entry in the "desktop.ini" file - now the position is saved properly, though its name is not localized anymore (not translated to the current system language).
It looked like this:
[LocalizedFileNames]
Computer Management.lnk=@%SystemRoot%\system32\mycomput.dll,-300

